# How to remove all “alien contacts” appeared after importing contacts from an exported CSV file?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, import

After I exported my Gmail Contacts to a `.csv` file and reimported them back, I got the “alien” contacts as in the below screenshot—they have no name and something related to Google+.

How can I remove all of those automatically?

[image]

[image]

Check the exported .csv file we can see that there are entries of these "alien" ones as below snapshot.

[image]

Comment: These are probably contacts that you sent some email to at some point and you knew only the email address, so they have been automatically added to your _Other Contacts_. But I have no idea how to remove them all at once.

Comment: I don't think it relates to email since there is no email in the contact detail

Comment: That’s strange; and you don’t see them in the CVS file?

Comment: Is CVS really the filetype and not CSV?

Comment: @batpigandme Thanks. It is CSV and I've corrected my OP

Comment: @Alex Yes I can see it in the CSV file (not CVS). And I have updated my OP to reflex this.

Comment: Those are _probably_ people that you had once Circled in Google+ and then later unCircled. It used to be that doing so would leave behind remnants in your contacts, although that no longer happens. As for getting rid of them, can you merge them?

Comment: Or, more likely, are they listed under the special "Other Contacts" group? You should be able to check and remove in bulk.

Comment: @AlEverett I can only see those "aliean" contacts on my mobile phone, the Samsung Galaxy Nexus, and on Gmail web site, going to Contacts we see none of these. So I cannot merge them.

Comment: With Google contacts you can select all them (one click each) and delete them in one step.